# Function always return false when using .then() inside loop .each()

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, each, protractor, angular-promise

When calling the function from Spec the code is running fine the 'aria-label' is verified/checked but true/false is not returned back to spec to check .toBe(true)

**Page Object: Function**

```
checkOptionsEnabled: function(){
        var status = false;
        element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).then(function(options) {
             options.forEach(function(option) {
                    option.getAttribute("aria-label").then(function(ariaLabel) {
                    expect(ariaLabel).toContain('enabled');                
                });
            });
        });
        return status;
    },
```

**Spec: Calling function**

```
page.journeyModes.checkAll.click();
expect(page.journeyModes.checkOptionsEnabled()).toBe(true);
page.journeyModes.uncheckAll.click();
expect(page.journeyModes.checkOptionsDisabled()).toBe(true);
```

**Error**

```
 1) TravelInfo As a user I can Select Journey Modes
  Message:
    Expected false to be true.
  Stacktrace:
    Error: Expected false to be true.
   at new jasmine.ExpectationResult
```

C:\Users\sunil.sharma\Documents\PortalAutomatedTests\node_modules\protractor\n
   de_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:137:32)
    at [object Object].

Comment: I need to verify that once the **CheckAll** button is clicked() all the **options are selected** and vice versa.
_ariaLabel toggles Enabled and Disabled class based on select and unselect_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce):

```
checkOptionsEnabled: function() {
    return element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).reduce(function(acc, elem) {
        return elem.getAttribute("aria-label").then(function (attr) {
            return acc && (attr.indexOf("enabled") >= 0);
        });        
    }, true);
},
```

This is basically checking the presence of `enabled` in `aria-label` attribute and accumulates the result boolean value.

Comment: Thanks  It work for me by replacing **option.getAttribute** with **elem.getAttribute**.